# How make axios request using layer services in React js without headers token authorization

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt

before it used a header as follows:

```
const token = Cookies.get("token");
const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };
```

Now, i created a service where i instantiate axios as follows:

```
export const api = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
});
```

This is the services:

```
// providerService.js
import { api } from "./axiosConfig";

export const providerService = {
  getJobs: async () => {
    const response = await api.request({
      url: "/provider/myJobs",
      method: "GET",
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  },
};
```

This is the my petition:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const jobs = await providerService.getJobs();
        console.log(jobs);
      } catch (error) {
        // console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

As I add the `withCredentials: true,` parameter. I think that is not necessary send the `headers`. But I am getting the following error by API:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/provider/myJobs' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

GET http://localhost:3000/provider/myJobs net::ERR_FAILED 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Answer (score 0):

Token wasn't added in headers `axios.create` , because of that it throwing 401, unauthorized request.

You can add headers like this,

```
export const api = axios.create({
    headers: {
      Authorization : `Bearer ${token}`
    },
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
});
```

You can go to axios docs for more info